# Key error after changing the Dataframe's column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe from a website and have used the first few rows as the `Date` . It shows me a Df with `Yr_Mn_Dy` but it dowsnt lok nice so I wanted to change it to `Dates`.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/guipsamora/pandas_exercises/master/06_Stats/Wind_Stats/wind.data', sep='\s+', parse_dates = [[0,1,2]] )
df.head()

    Yr_Mo_Dy    RPT ... BEL MAL
0   2061-01-01  15.04   ... 18.50   15.04
1   2061-01-02  14.71   ... 17.54   13.83
2   2061-01-03  18.50   ... 12.75   12.71
3   2061-01-04  10.58   ... 5.46    10.88
4   2061-01-05  13.33   ... 12.92   11.83
```

I have used 2 different methods one by one

```
1. df.rename(columns= {'Yr_Mo_Dy': 'Dates'})  # it does not work. it is not changing the columns names to Dates

and 

2. df.columns.values[0]='Dates'  # it changes the values when used with df.head() but throws Key error for Dates
```

**1. Why  is the first method not changing the value and renaming the column?**

**2. Even after changing the value with second method, why is it  throwing a `Dates` Key error?**

Comment: You didn't assign the `df` back or use `inplace`. Try `df.rename(columns= {'Yr_Mo_Dy': 'Dates'},inplace=True)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First method could change the column name,  it works nicely in my computer,

please noted that it doesn't change the original dataframe, it is returning a new dataframe instead, to make the change permanent,

```
df.rename(columns= {'Yr_Mo_Dy': 'Dates'},inplace=True)
```

Second method is also working, it doesn't throw Dates Key error.